Kafka Deserialization Issue with DTOs across Microservices in Spring Boot. Class Not in Trusted Packages
I am currently working on a spring boot application with microservice architecture. I have a auth service that produces messages and a user service which consumes them. I am having trouble deserialising the messages in consumer.
I currently produce messages on 2 events

On user registration in auth service with the DTO

public record UserDTO(
     UUID id,
     String username,
     String email,
     Role role
) {
}
// Note: I use same name for records accros service


On email chage for a user

public record EmailChangeDTO(
        String username,
        @NonNull String email
) {
}

I use String serialization for Key and JsonSerialization for value. But when I try to deserialize the coming message in the user service I encounter the below error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.example.authservice.Dto.EmailChangeDTO' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.example.userservice.DTO]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).

same for user registration as well.
my consumer looks like below
package com.example.userservice.Config;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String,Object> consumerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "user-service-group");

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);

        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES,"com.userservice.userservice.DTO");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}

I even tried adding the package from auth in trusted packages but I get the below error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.authservice.Dto.UserDTO

But when try to deserialize the key as a String and then use objectmapper to map it to the DTO in the userservice it works perfectly.
@KafkaListener(topics = "customer-registration", groupId = "user-service-group")
    public void consumeUserRegistration(String message) {
        try {
            log.info("Received user registration event: {}", message);
            UserDTO userDTO = objectMapper.readValue(message, UserDTO.class);
            userService.createUser(userDTO);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Error processing user registration event", e);
        }
    }

How should I configure Kafka’s JsonDeserializer to properly trust DTO classes from multiple packages?
Is using ObjectMapper for manual deserialization a good approach in this case, or is there a more efficient way?

Typo? Dto is not capitalized in your class

No in the authservice the package name is Dto and in userservice its DTO.

You need to add authservice classes to your userservice code to resolve ClassNotFoundException. You'll also need to fix com.userservice.userservice in your config

So, you send com.example.authservice.Dto.UserDTO, but expect com.userservice.userservice.DTO.UserDTO. That's definitely has nothing to do with trusted packages since you fully try to ignore type info sent by the producer. For that purpose you need to look into types mapping: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#serdes-mapping-types
consumerProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, 
           "com.example.authservice.Dto.UserDTO:com.userservice.userservice.DTO.UserDTO");

